# how sparse columns have retrieving overhead?

Tags: sql-server, sparse-matrix

In following link
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns"
"Sparse columns reduce the space requirements for null values at the cost of more overhead to retrieve non null values."

Q1. Please explain how the cost in retrieval increases?

Q2) Please confirm the cost they are talking about is non null sparse col or the cost of non null normal col will also increase.

yours sincerely

Comment: Based on the fact that NULL values take up no space and populated values use an extra 4 bytes... I'd be inclined to believe that marking a column as sparse, simply moves that column to a new table behind the scenes, using a 4 byte int to to relate it back to the main table. The "hidden join" would also account for the stated performance hit. I can't prove that theory based on the documentation I've skimmed over in the last 10 mins but it seems to make logical sense.

Comment: Regarding your second question, and assuming that @JasonA.Long got it right, an additional overhead might come from the need to perform an in-place pivoting of data in order to return the non-NULL values as parts of the same row. Not to mention that if you are accessing the column set, an XML has to be (de)constructed in situ, as well.

Comment: That means, if i do not have space issue, then i should not use sparse col?

or there can be some caveats.

Comment: i will never get sparce col in select , it is for rare use.so the cols i get will be nonsparse cols only , 
so the question is, in above case will it slow my queries in any way, 

yoursincerly